# Fleurons and indentations

Tags: indentation, classicthesis

I'm trying to change the indentation settings on my latex documents.
ATM, every paragraph is indented by default. I would fill the space of the indentation with a symbol, e.g. a fleuron.

Obviously, starting each paragraph with

```
\noindent
**Symbol** Lorem ipsum...
```

can be an idea, but I'm looking for a more automatic solution, if it's not too hard to implement. I'm using the style Classicthesis by André Miede, I don't know if this can affect the possible solution in some way.

Thanks for your time,
Nigredo

Comment: I assume you are not writing a thesis but, even so, why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, it's not for a thesis. I use classicthesis, with some ad hoc changes, for almost everything since for me is a very well balanced template, from a typographical point of view. I was trying to set up a book in an old fashioned way, so I'd use fleurons as I described above.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\everypar`. See section 16.2 of [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\everypar{$\rip$}
This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image: paragraph]

Comment: Although I note your example doesn't include `\section{this is a section}` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I didn't know that `\section` changed `\everypar`. No doubt there are a few other things as well.

Comment: section does change it  (to suppress the indentation following) but the main problem is that it _doesn_t change it for the heading itself which is internally a paragraph. latex lists change \everypar all over the place as well (and almost every display environment is a list:-). It's still the right answer, probably, but the user needs to be aware:-)

Comment: Yep, there are two problems I noticed:
1. \everypar{} must be declared every time a new section starts.
2. \everypar{} indents the first line of the section too.